# Copy Paste not working on System.Windows.Forms.TextBox when running on Mac

Tags: macos, winforms, textbox, cross-platform

I am building a .NET C# Windows Forms application with cross-platform capability as required by my company's client. The application was built and running fine on Windows PC. However, when it is deployed on Mac, something wrong happened. One of them is the copy-paste feature, which is now not working. No matter how I tried to press Ctrl-C/Ctrl V, or use right click and choose Copy/Paste, I still can't copy any text to any textbox of the application. Can anyone please tell me how to make Winforms textbox copiable and pastable on Mac? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac does not support Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V instead you have to use MAC key in place of Ctrl key and if you are using window supported keyword then use Window key in place of Ctrl.

Here is the shortcut key combination for MAC:

[Keyboard shortcut keys for MAC](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/keyboard-shortcuts-mac-users-copy-paste-option-shortcuts-3504584/)

Comment: @anthony_netdev_2016, if you find it useful please mark it as answer so it will help others too.

Comment: That's very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote for you. I need 15 reputation points to do so.

Comment: @anthony_netdev_2016, That's not a issue my concern is to help only.